# which data type and length is suitable for the field of auto increment id in database?

Tags: database, types, auto-increment

Let's say my website will be like Facebook which has a lot of entry everyday. So the entry for the field of auto increment id in database should be a lot lot lot. Instead of INT without specify the Length/Values, should I use BIGINT with 50 Length/Values for the id field?

Comment: If you expect more rows than the capacity of one datatype then yes, of course you would use a datatype with greater capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the database you are using, read the manual and look for the largest capacity integer datatype, and go for it.

If you use MySQL (since you are using phpmyadmin), the largest capacity integer datatype is `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

With it, you can represent integers from 0 up to 18446744073709551615.

Note that `SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`.

That means, you should go for `SERIAL`.

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin database.

Comment: 18446744073709551615 has 20 digits only. If I assign length 50, it will still accept 20 digits only, it won't accept 50 digits right?